# Object becomes unaligned after constraining and moving objects

Tags: animation, constraints

-I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://vimeo.com/6611513) on Blender constraints. I tried to simplify it to two objects and two empties. The cylinder at the origin works fine. With the smaller cylinder, I added a Track To constraint to the Empty on the origin, and I added a Child Of constraint to the outer Empty. However, when I move the outer Empty down, the smaller cylinder becomes unaligned with the setup (the empty and cylinders don't make a straight line like the piston in the tutorial does). Does anyone have ideas on fixes?

-What I think is the problem is that the Child Of constraint in the smaller cylinder keeps it -5 units in the y direction from the outer empty, causing problems. I thought the the tutorial used the same  constraint and did fine.

[image: constraint problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to remove all constraints on the cylinder, set its origin to the empty's location, and then put back the constraints (I skipped that part from the tutorial on accident).  So from what I learned, an object's origin is important in constraints.